# Is there a way to set Grunt to open a Sublime project file

Tags: gruntjs, sublimetext2, workflow

To begin working on a project, my usual actions look like:

1. to open iTerm, `cd` to my local repo,
2. initialize `grunt`
3. Open Sublim
4. Navigate to recent projects
5. Click relevant project file

I'd like to cut 3-5 steps if I can and program grunt to open the Sublime app and specifically the project in that file. Is that possible?

I've seen tools like this: https://github.com/tvooo/sublime-grunt but they're about Sublime working Grunt not so much Grunt working Sublime.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There's a [grunt plugin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) to run shell commands, so it should work once you  set up [subl](https://gist.github.com/artero/1236170)